# Bluetooth or WiFi Thermal Printer

Tags: android, printing, thermal-printer

I want to print token number from my android application using WiFi or Bluetooth. I have implemented PrintManager API but the problem is that after click on print it is asking to choose printer from list of printer. My requirement is that once I choose or configured printer with app it should not ask again to choose printer. My questions are below -

1. Is that possible using PrintManager API?
2. I am ready to use thermal printer . Which manufacturer provide thermal printer with SDK or sample code?

Comment: I've already made an application which do all you need: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pe.diegoveloper.printerserverapp  , you can integrate your app with mine

Answer (score 1):

To answer (2) you can give [StarMicronics](https://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx) a try, it comes with bunch of sample code for different platforms. The way we do is to configure the MAC address of the printer somehow (Restful API, database, etc.) and try to find the printer's IP (on the first use) and cache it for subsequent uses.

For (1), I had no practical experience with PrintManager, but normally the app contact printer via SDK. There are abstract layer (in case you need to work with another printer's vendor) such as [JavaPOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285875/javapos-on-android-devices).

Answer (score 0):

Follow Any [Blue Printer](https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-bluetooth-tutorial/) or Any Network Printer SKD
you said that Already Have Printer SDK

Then Go the Find Printer/Printer Discovery file after Finding Printer

Just Save the Printer Credentials with [Shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

and At next Run Always choose Shared preference.. if there is no Printer get start your Find Printer

For Additional Details Give Your Printer SDK Link I will Update Shared preference in it